# How can I achieve the First Emblem of Pot Achievement of Master Chef II?

Tags: glitch-2011

How do I [gain "the right to learn the savory secrets of Master Chef II"](http://www.glitch.com/achievements/spent-first-emblem-of-pot/)?

Comment: aww, I liked it when it was ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emblems are special items given by gods when your favor with one of them reaches 1000. You can garner favor with gods by doing quests (which often assign a number of favor points to a particular god associated with the task you completed) or by donating to the shrine of a specific god. Donations award xp (up to a daily cap) and favor, the amount of which is proportional to the value of the item donated.

[This particular emblem](http://www.glitch.com/items/emblem-of-pot/) is gained by donating to the god Pot and enables you to learn [Master Chef II](http://www.glitch.com/skills/48/). All emblems are tied to a specific high-level skill which you unlock when you earn the emblem.